# Client Side OAuth

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, oauth

So I'm trying to make a SPA that uses Magento 1.9.2.2 as its back office.  To do this, I would like to use its REST API.  And of course, it forces you to OAuth with Magento first.  I have tried multiple ways to OAuth with it on the client, my own way which works fine with any of the popular OAuth1.0a services like Twitter and LinkedIn, I've also tried using this https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a which also works with things that don't constantly break, *cough* magento *cough*.  The issue I have is that I get back a 401 status saying signature invalid.  This is the gist of it using the module:

```
var oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        public: 'a604a470aaff57d6063800aef713a12a',
        secret: 'ecdbb5cb43c9299ab3372ad973792d47'
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
});
var reqData = {
    url: '/oauth/initiate',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        oauth_callback: 'https://172.22.22.24/oauth/authorize'
    }
};
var authData = oauth.authorize(reqData);
$.ajax({
    url: reqData.url,
    type: reqData.method,
    data: authData,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

So if I were to reconfigure this for any other OAuth1.0a service, it works fine.  Wh would it be that magento does not? Additionally, I have gone through all the Admin configuration for Authing with REST

Comment: Did you try the OAuth authentication like in these examples here? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html Wonder if this works then (even if it's not the way you want to use it).

Comment: See that'd be good and all, if I was trying to do it server side.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Just wondering if this is a general problem or just the way you're trying to authenticate.

Comment: And as far as the steps taken to authenticate, yes that is exactly what I am doing, but in Javascript.

Comment: Well it's definitely magento specific considering this way of auth'ing works pretty much anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue turned out to be that HMAC-SHA1 in Crypto.js and HMAC-SHA1 in Magento do not work together.  So unfortunately, the solution is use PLAINTEXT as the signature method.

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to use SSL, even along with OAuth, otherwise sensitive  data can be intercepted by someone (in your case customer or order details).
OAuth 1.0a at most can guarantee that data was not modified by man-in-the-middle, but has no data encryption mechanisms and thus leaves the payload readable by anyone.

At the same time, when SSL is enabled, there is no benefits in using signatures. So in your case it should be absolutely acceptable to use PLAINTEXT signature method with enabled SSL (in your example you use https, so you seem to have it already enabled). This will even work a little bit faster since there is no need to calculate and verify signature on each request.